# Compare two sets of data frames (strings)

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, geopy

I have two pandas data frames: test_df and golden_df. There are poastal addresses in each of these frames. Basically, the test_df is user entered and may have several mistakes (missing street/pincode/incorrect formatting/etc.) - I have used the Google API to correct these issues and format the addresses of test_df.
Next, using the golden_df - I have to see which addresses are present in test_df and which are not.

I am not an expert and hence the first isea I got was using a for loop read each address in test_df and search for it in golden_df - yes this works - but I know there has to be a batter and more efficient way.
My data set is large - it may contain upto 150000 rows. I have shared a few for representation below:

```
#test_df:

data = ["941 Thorpe St, Rock Springs, WY 82901",
    "2809 Harris Dr, Antioch, CA 94509",
    "7 Eucalyptus, Newport Coast, CA 92657",
    "725 Mountain View St, Altadena, CA 91001",
    "1966 Clinton Ave, Calexico, CA 92231",
    "431 6th St, West Sacramento, CA 95605",
    "5574 Old Goodrich Rd, Clarence, NY 14031",
    "Valencia Way, Valley Center, CA 92082"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['parsed addresses'])
```

```
#golden_df:

data = ["941 Thorpe St, Rock Springs, WY 82901",
    "2809 Harris Dr, Antioch, CA 94509",
    "8838 La Jolla Scenic Dr N, La Jolla, CA 92037",
    "16404 Parthenia St North Hills, CA 91343",
    "1966 Clinton Ave, Calexico, CA 92231",
    "431 6th St, West Sacramento, CA 95605",
    "1010 Hillcroft Rd, Glendale, CA 91207",
    "Valencia Way, Valley Center, CA 92082"]
golden_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['golden addresses'])
```

This is what I had started to write:

```
for i in range(0, len(test_df)):
    each_add = test_df.at[i,"parsed addresses"]
    golden_df['golden addresses'].str.contains(row_add)
```

Given the number of rows - what is the best approach?

My goal is to get the number of correct matches.

Edited to add latest update:

I am trying:

`data_intersection = gold_add.loc[gold_add["golden address"].isin(test_add["parsed address"]),"golden address"]`

I see that `len(data_intersection)` is > test_add.shape[0]

How can this be true if the function computes common data in both test and golden dataframes?

I also tried to convert the addresses to set. The `len(set(golden_df['golden addresses'])` and the number of rows in `golden_df.shape[0]` is not equal. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you manually type out your expected output for this test case?

Comment: You can post something u did? We can try to help u from there

Comment: I would skip pandas and just use `set()` on those list of strings. In both --> `len(set(test_data).intersection(gold_data))`

Comment: I tried to convert my column to set. The `len(set(golden_df['golden addresses'])` and the number of rows in `golden_df.shape[0]` is not same. 
Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Use `isin`:

```
>>> golden_df.loc[golden_df["golden addresses"].isin(test_df["parsed addresses"]),"golden addresses"]

0    941 Thorpe St, Rock Springs, WY 82901
1        2809 Harris Dr, Antioch, CA 94509
4     1966 Clinton Ave, Calexico, CA 92231
5    431 6th St, West Sacramento, CA 95605
7    Valencia Way, Valley Center, CA 92082
Name: golden addresses, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you - will this be good even on large data (150k such addresses each in `test_df` and `golden_df`)?

Comment: Yes, should be fine.

Comment: I was working on this - looks like the length of `data_intersection` is more than the length of `test_df`
How can this be true?

Comment: It cannot. You're doing something wrong. Post a *representative* example where this situation occurs.